# PHP - getting the values that are only checked in a looped table after submitting

Tags: php, mysql

Basically my form will have to add credits to the registered users that was checked in the table that was loaded in the page. When the user clicks the submit button, the registered users which are checked will have an additional credits. My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the rows that are checked in the looped table. Here is my code.

```
<form name="blah" method="POST" action="">
<?php
include("mysql_config.php");
// INITIAL OUTPUT WHEN THE PAGE IS LOADED
echo "<table class='sample'><tr>
<td></td>
<td><b>User ID</b></td>
<td><b>Username</b></td>
<td><b>First Name</b></td>
<td><b>Last Name</b></td>
<td><b>Credits</b></td>
</tr>";
$q = "SELECT * FROM users_credits";
$res = mysql_query($q);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $reg_id = $db_field['reg_id'];
    $credits = $db_field['credits'];
    $q2 = "SELECT username, fn, ln FROM reg_users WHERE reg_id = $reg_id";
    $res2 = mysql_query($q2);
    $db_field2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
    $username = $db_field2['username'];
    $fn = $db_field2['fn'];
    $ln = $db_field2['ln'];
    echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='$i' name='add_credit'></td>
        <td>$reg_id</td>
        <td>$username</td>
        <td>$fn</td>
        <td>$ln</td>
        <td>$credits</td>
        </tr>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" >
</form>
```

Thanks in advance to the persons who'll help me. :)

Comment: You hvae a bug in your code. value=$i should be value='$i'

Comment: You need a unique name on each input element, like add_credit[$i]

Comment: thanks for the responses. i'm still developing this form. will follow your advice. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your page as :

```
<form name="blah" method="POST" action="update.php">
<?php
include("mysql_config.php");
// INITIAL OUTPUT WHEN THE PAGE IS LOADED
echo "<table class='sample'><tr>
<td></td>
<td><b>User ID</b></td>
<td><b>Username</b></td>
<td><b>First Name</b></td>
<td><b>Last Name</b></td>
<td><b>Credits</b></td>
</tr>";
$q = "SELECT * FROM users_credits";
$res = mysql_query($q);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

    while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    $reg_id = $db_field['reg_id'];
    $credits = $db_field['credits'];
    $q2 = "SELECT username, fn, ln FROM reg_users WHERE reg_id = $reg_id";
    $res2 = mysql_query($q2);
    $db_field2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
    $username = $db_field2['username'];
    $fn = $db_field2['fn'];
    $ln = $db_field2['ln'];
    echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='".$reg_id."' name='add_credit[]'></td>
        <td>$reg_id</td>
        <td>$username</td>
        <td>$fn</td>
        <td>$ln</td>
        <td>$credits</td>
        </tr>";
}
?>
```

Make the form action in update.php as

```
<?php
$users=$_REQUEST['add_credit'];

if(is_array($users))
{
foreach($users as $key=>$val)
{

echo $val;

}

}
?>
```

Here you will get the users id in array.

Comment: I've followed your advice and it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: If it is so you can accept the answer..by checking the button right..

Answer (score 0):

Write a Javascript function to be called, when the button is clicked -

```
function updateFilter(){
        var tmp="";
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('<checkbox id>');
        for(var i in checkboxes){
            if(checkboxes[i].checked)
                tmp=tmp + "," + checkboxes[i].value;
        }
        tmp=tmp.substring(1);   
        parent.window.location.href="<file to open>.php?p=" + tmp;
    }
```

Your HTML for checkbox would look like this -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="p<checkbox id>" value="<?php echo $row['Product_ID']; ?>"
```

Ideally this would concatenate all the values of checkbox and pass it as a parameter (in this case PHP) and it could be decoded in next page as

```
$r=mysql_query("select * from product_master where Product_ID in (" . $p.")");
```

Or using split. I would recommend that value of checkbox should be IDs instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

Change your checkbox to this:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='$reg_id' name='add_credit[]'>
```

Then when you post to your action you will have a list of all the checked users' reg_id. It will be an array that you can access with $_POST['add_credit']